# Mysterious problems appending data frames with rbind

Tags: r, memory-management, append, rbind

I am in a dilly of a pickle trying to join several files together into a master file. There are 5 files with same structure, and I can read each file individually into a data frame with no problems. I even manually set the column class for 200+ variables rather than letting R decide, because I believed that was causing the problem. However, appending any two files together causes me to run out of memory.

> Warning messages:
>   1: In rbind(deparse.level, ...) :
>    Reached total allocation of 4043Mb: see help(memory.size)

So I did some experimenting:
I joined two different chunks of file 1 together. That works.
I joined a chunk of file 2 to a chunk of file 1. That works.
I joined a chunk of file 2 to the original file 1. That works.

Each of these files comes in at a little under 200MB so I am not sure that I should be running out of memory. If anybody is interested, the data comes from [hearstchallenge.com](http://www.hearstchallenge.com). The competition is long over, we are just using the data for an analysis experiment (and not programming!).

Any suggestions for how to solve this?

Comment: +1 for "dilly of a pickle".  The problem you're running into is that R needs 4043 contiguous MB of memory to complete the operation.  And I assume you don't have that much to spare.  You can try using a command line tool like `sed` to join the files outside of R, or one of the big data packages like `ff`.

Comment: `write.table` also has an `append` option.

Comment: @Oliver I take it you're on a 32bit machine?

Comment: I am using a new-ish 64bit model.

Comment: `> system("cat file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 >>big.ass.file")`

Comment: @Oliver there are several solutions here already that don't involve extending R's memory limit, but if you're on a 64bit system, R should be able to use a lot more than ~4GB. You could start R with the `--max-mem-size=6000M` flag (leave out the `=6000M` to use max available), or if you're on Windows, you can request a bigger limit on the fly with the `memory.limit` function.

Comment: I will check into all ideas offered so far. I will need to not only join the files, but then save and re-load it a handful of times. I am especially intrigued/puzzled by Carl's "big.ass.file" method.

Comment: To be a bit more serious: it does depend on what OS, and Windows is a bit of a pain. I haven't really figured out what it takes to reliably get `system()` calls to `cmd.exe` to perform as desired.

Comment: check out `rbindlist` from the `data.table` package, I think ...

Comment: Oops -- using `shell` will be much easier than using `system`

Answer (score 1):

I have run into similar problems.  The solution is not to use rbind() or cbind() on large data.  They tend to leak memory.

To solve your problem using only R, first create a dataframe of the dimensions that the dataframe would have after you put the pieces together.  Then use assignments to fill in the large dataframe.

Comment: For big data, don't use data.frames, use data.tables.